# Log what page the user is currently on

Tags: php

I have a chatroom on my website. I want to compile a list of online users in the chatroom.

What is the best way to do this? 
Would it be to log the last page the user visited and if it was that page, they are in the chatroom?

What different techniques can be used to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Comet in your chat application, then you'll have a channel open to the server, which would be bound to the client side as an open HTTP request.

As long as that request is open, the user is in the room.  If the request closes, then the user is no longer in the room.

Comment: I have never heard of Comet, I am using the chat package Yshout

Comment: If you're using a third party package and not something you built, then your pageview idea would be somewhat okay.  I don't know if you could necessarily tell if someone left the room or not.  It depends on whether or not the chat window is on your domain or not.  If it is, you could put a window.setTimeout in place to periodically ping your webserver with a keepalive that says "I'm still here!".

Comment: Yeah the chat window is on my own server. I like this idea of using a settimeout. Should I google it? Regarding what I originally proposed, if a user opened a second window on a second tab, surely that would mean the chatroom would think they aren't there?

Comment: As long as that window is open, your user should be "in the room".  window.setTimeout(function() { /* make ajax call to your server here with the user's name */ },60000);  // makes keepalive request every 60 seconds.

Comment: So the window remains open and therefore the user list for that URL is populated by that window being open. What is the best way to do this then?

Comment: The setTimeout function takes a function as 1 parameter and a timeout value X as another.  Every X milliseconds the browser runs the function, which in your case will need to send a message to your server that updates your database or a session object with the user's name so it can be put in a global list.

Comment: Ahhh this sounds ideal, therefore even if they move onto another page (2nd tab), they are still hitting the server with a request and therefore are still in the chatroom.

Comment: You got it!  Exactly.  You're not interested in what page they're on, just that they are still receiving messages from your chat room :)

Answer (score 0):

Yshout works by doing an AJAX request against yshout/yshout.php every 6 seconds. Add a bit of code to yshout.php to track how many unique users it's seen in the last 10 seconds, and you should be set.

**Edit:** you want the **names** of everyone active in the chatroom? I'd be tempted to add a database table for this - every time they hit yshout.php, add a name+timestamp entry and delete all entries more than 10 seconds old. Then query with GROUP BY name to get unique users.

**Edit 2:** The chat client **already does** an AJAX request on yshout.php every six seconds. All you have to do is add a snippet of PHP code inside the 'if (isset($_POST['reqFor']))' clause (the bit that responds to the AJAX requests).

Keep it brief! Remember, it's going to get hammered on something like 150 times per minute.

Comment: Quality idea. I think this is the one I will go with. To generate an up to date list, use AJAX request every 6 seconds to update list and delete anything older than 10 seconds?

Comment: So you think the best idea is to put the PHP within that reqFor that goes to the database, adds a new record and deletes old ones?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [sessions](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) javascript library to record each page the user has visited and then retrieve those values in your chat client via javascript.

- include the library on each page.
- in the sessvars object, make an array `sessvars.visited = [];` [if sessvars.visited is not already an array]
- Now on each page do something like this `sessvars.visited[] = location.href`
- On the chat client page, use javascript to iterate through `sessvars.visited` to obtain all the URLs. For example, To list out the URLs in HTML w/ Jquery do the following:

---

```
var urlList = '';
$.each(sessvars.visited, function(key, value){
    urlList += value + '<br />';
})
```

Note: Sessvars is an alternative to Cookies that has a very large capacity (10mb in most browsers). However, session data is only available in an active window. Information is lost once the window is closed, and as far as I know cannot be queried from other windows. So if chat is open in a different window than they were browsing in, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a javascript request to the server every x seconds.

You already have to do this (for retrieving the ongoing chat conversation and the list of users participating).

On the server side you know what users are on because of this request. You just have to log these requests.